# How to test multi-thread/concurrency method correctly in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, googletest

I want to test these functions with google unit test.

```
std::vector<int> vec;
std::mutex vec_mutex;  // protects vec
void safe_add(int i)
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(vec_mutex);
    vec.push_back(i);    
}

void safe_clear()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(vec_mutex);
    vec.clear();
}
```

How can I pause one thread in specific conditions or in a specific line of code?

Comment: Set aside a separate mutex and a condition variable, and a `bool` flag, just for this specific task.

Comment: What do mean by pause?

Comment: @JakeFreeman I mean How can I freeze a thread...?

Comment: @SamMokari perhaps using `Sleep()`

Comment: @JakeFreeman We cannot make sure sleep works for this problem